# Creating new map(m3) using map1 values and m2 keys

Tags: developer-console

I want to create a new map(map3) and add new elements in map3 dynamically with help of map1 values and m2 keys using logic.I want output like map3 values {abc=4, bcd=5, dcb=6}. can somebody please help. Thanks in advance.

```
        Map<String,Integer> m1 = new Map<String,Integer>();
        
        m1.put('abc',1);
        m1.put('bcd',2);
        m1.put('dcb',3);
        
        System.debug(' map values '+ m1);
        
        Map<Integer,Integer> m2 = new Map<Integer,Integer>();
        
        m2.put(1,4);
        m2.put(2,5);
        m2.put(3,6);    
        System.debug(' map values '+ m2);
        Map<String,Integer> m3 = new Map<String,Integer>();
        System.debug(' map values '+ m3);
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. This question does not contain enough information for anyone to help you. For the best experience here, please read [ask] and [help/on-topic] carefully, then [edit] your post to show _what you've tried_ and _where you're stuck_, with plenty of detail.

Comment: @DavidReed why you made it off-topic, since question is updated and I provided working answer?

Comment: I didn't close this question. Community voting did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
Map<String,Integer> m3 = new Map<String,Integer>();
for (String m1Key : m1.keySet()) {
    Integer m2Key = m1.get(m1Key);
    m3.put(m1Key, m2.get(m2Key));
}

System.debug(' map values '+ m3);
```

You iterate keys of `m1` and get information from `m2` to put in `m3`.

You might also want to add check for `m2.containsKey(m2Key)`

Comment: Thanks so much ytiq code worked

Comment: cool, please then accept my answer, so the question is closed